# Manually linkup UIButton declared in XIB and property in VIewController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

XCode require you to declared stuffs like `IBAction` and `IBOutlet` and then you need to use **MOUSE** to link up the reference outlets, which is the thing I hate so much.

I want to link up the items declared in `XIB`  programmatically, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be you should try to add buttons also programmatically. Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
CGRect myButtonFrame = CGRectMake(70, 200, 180, 60);
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(MyButtonAction)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myButton.frame = myButtonFrame;
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

}

```
-(void)MyButtonAction
{
NSLog(@"ACTION");
}
```

Comment: Because I want to move the code like `CGRect myButtonFrame = CGRectMake(70, 200, 180, 60);` to xib, so I don't need to hard code them in code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But not recommended though.
You could assign tag to your control and then use `[self.view viewWithTag:TAG];` message. Or you could lookup for desired control in `self.view.subviews` array.
But anyway, you'd better don't do that.

Comment: Because your code will be completely unreadable and very hard to support. When you're working in team or even your code may become public you should avoid such style.